# How do I break a binary number in parts? C language

Tags: c, binary, break, bit, ieee

I have an assignment that requires me to convert a float number into an IEEE 754 binary representation. I already got the bits part done, but I don't know how to break the number into parts (signal, exponential and fraction). Here's the code I have:

```
typedef unsigned char Byte;

void showbits(char str[], Byte data[], int size) {

    int i, j;
    int bit;



    printf ("%s = ", str);

    for(i = size-1; i>=0; i--){
        for(j = 7; j >= 0; j--){
            bit = (data[i] >> j) & 1;

            printf ("%d", bit);
        }
        printf (" ");
    }
    printf ("\n");
    printf("signal: %d\n", (data[size - 1] >> 7) & 1);

    printf("exponential: ");

            printf("%d", (data[size-2] >> 6) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[size-3] >> 5) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[size-4] >> 4) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[size-5] >> 3) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[size-6] >> 2) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[size-7] >> 1) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[size-8] >> 0) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[size-9] >> 7) & 1);

    printf("\nfraction: ");

            printf("%d", (data[21] >> 6) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[20] >> 5) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[19] >> 4) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[18] >> 3) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[17] >> 2) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[16] >> 1) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[15] >> 0) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[14] >> 7) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[13] >> 6) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[12] >> 5) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[11] >> 4) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[10] >> 3) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[9] >> 2) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[8] >> 1) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[7] >> 0) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[6] >> 7) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[5] >> 6) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[4] >> 5) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[3] >> 4) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[2] >> 3) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[1] >> 2) & 1);
            printf("%d", (data[0] >> 1) & 1);

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    float f;

    scanf("%f", &f);

    showbits("float", (Byte *)&f, sizeof(float));

    return 0;
}
```

Also, can someone explain me why there's a loop there that starts at 7 and goes to 0? I didn't do that part...
Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just show bits of `f` as is? They are already in  IEEE 754 representation

Comment: The assignment asks me to break it down into parts and say which part is which..

Comment: Still the same. The standard has the fixed meaning for fixed positions, so I don't see a problem.

Comment: Yes but how do i break it so that the first bit is in one print f, the next 8 bits are in another printf and the last 23 bits are in the last printf?

Comment: So you want not the bits but the values for sign, exponent and fraction parts?

Comment: Yes! For example:
12.5
Signal: 0
Exponential: 10000010
Fraction: 10010000000000000000000

Comment: I'm little bit drunk but seams to me you are trying to look too much bytes... data has just 4 bytes

Comment: Michele, you're not seeing double. Pedro: you should use *bits* where you now have *bytes* in your array.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you be more specific please? Sorry I'm new to this..

Answer (score 1):

"Also, can someone explain me why there's a loop there that starts at 7 and goes to 0? I didn't do that part... Thanks!"

This loop is to process a byte -- being that a byte is 8 bits so starting at 7 going to the inclusion of 0. The & 1 portion of it is to make sure only a single bit is stored in the variable bit. The function of this loop would be to print out the byte bit by bit.

Since you have the bits part done you can store that into something like a uint32_t or just an int if the values are no larger than 31 (sign having an effect on outcome)

For example

```
uint32_t exp = 0;
printf("exponential: ");

        exp |= ((data[size-2] >> 6) & 1) << 7;
        exp |= ((data[size-3] >> 5) & 1) << 6;
        exp |= ((data[size-4] >> 4) & 1) << 5;
        exp |= ((data[size-5] >> 3) & 1) << 4;
        exp |= ((data[size-6] >> 2) & 1) << 3;
        exp |= ((data[size-7] >> 1) & 1) << 2;
        exp |= ((data[size-8] >> 0) & 1) << 1;
        exp |= (data[size-9] >> 7) & 1;
```

This would store the bits in the same order as they are being printed out.

Comment: `size` will be 4 for a float so your `data[size-5]` and so on are wrong.